# How can I apply a glow filter in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, special-effects, phaser

I'm trying to get the following effect, but as far as I know, a filter is the only sensible way.

Imagine some objects and background, and a fire ball passing through. The fireball glows. All objects (not the background) become brighter in color where they are under that glow. The glow effect could be described as a glow around a missile's fire.

This should be built-in to Phaser, as pixi.js has it.

Comment: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/1444-how-to-use-pixi-masking-in-phaser/

Comment: You are talking about additive blending fyi. I don't know anything about Phaser so this isn't an answer, but that's the name of the filter to lookup.

Answer (score 2):

It may be achieved by following: add a glow sprite with additive blending mode (since it was introduced in Phaser 2.0 on March 13) and combine it with masking (you can find article on PIXI about masking [here](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixi-js-brings-canvas-and-webgl-masking/)).
So, the workflow:
- you render all your foreground objects, that need to be affected by glow to mask graphics
- render background and all foreground objects to real graphics
- use the mask graphics to set the mask of the glow sprites (set additive blending mode for them) and render the glows
Result: you get untouched background, and all foreground objects now are lit by glow sprites.

Comment: i think i get it but i am very new to pixijs and phaser so if you could make a small example i'd be very happy. Also i want other sprites to visible but extra lit when glow sprite is over them.Otherwise i could just lit them and unmask the lit part.

Comment: can you translate that into phaserjs code...i can't find a way to do `you render all your foreground objects, that need to be affected by glow to mask graphics`

Comment: can you give an example

Answer (score 0):

Look in [pixi.js/src/filters](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/tree/master/src/filters) or try [pixi-extra-filters/src/filters/glow](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-extra-filters/tree/master/src/filters/glow).

```
fireball.filters = [ new PIXI.filters.GlowFilter(viewWidth, viewHeight, distance, outerStrength, innerStrength, color, quality) ];
```